# go on first page not working

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

I'm trying to create a button to go on the first history page but I don't know why doesn't my code work.This is my code:

```js
function firstpg() {
  var startpt = '-' + window.history.length;
  window.history.go(startpt);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="firstpg()">Go First</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you need to add `-1` as the `length` will always contain something extra?

Answer (score 0):

The [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) also includes current page so you need to decrement `1` from the length in order go to the first page.

```
var startpt = '-' + ( window.history.length - 1) ;
```

or

```
var startpt = -(window.history.length - 1) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to negate the `length` as it is not `0` based. So try:

```
var startpt = ( window.history.length - 1) * -1;
```

This should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function firstpg() {
        var startpt = ( window.history.length - 1) * -1;
        window.history.go(startpt);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="firstpg()">Go First</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and easiest solution is ([window.history.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/length)):

```
window.history.go(1 - window.history.length);
```

Where the following mathematical operation has been simplified:

```
(window.history.length - 1) * -1
(window.history.length * -1) - (1 * -1)
-windows.history.length - (-1)
-windows.history.length + 1
1 - windows.history.length
```